# WordPress - How to load assets only for a single dashboard widget

Tags: php, wordpress, vue.js

I'm writing a custom wordpress plugin that will add a widget to the default wordpress dashboard. The plugin will be used as a ticketing system, and the front end will be created using vuejs. I'm having some problem to send emails using wp-ajax so I'm thinking to create a custom rest route to manage the data that will be sent from the widget. At the moment this is the php code that I'm using to init the widget into the dashboard

```php
<?php 

/*
*   Plugin Name: Internal Support Ticket System
*   Description: Ticketing System
*   Version: 1.0
*/

class supportTicketSystem {

    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', [$this, 'setup_ticketing_widget']);
        add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', [$this, 'enqueue_widget_scripts']);
    }

    public function setup_ticketing_widget()
    {
        // Remove Welcome panel.
        remove_action( 'welcome_panel', 'wp_welcome_panel' );

        // Remove all Dashboard widgets.
        //global $wp_meta_boxes;
        //unset( $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard'] );
        
        // Add custom dashbboard widget.
        add_meta_box( 'dashboard_widget_example',
            __( 'Richiesta ticket di supporto'),
            [$this, 'ticketing_widget_content'],
            'dashboard',
            'side',  // $context: 'advanced', 'normal', 'side', 'column3', 'column4'
            'high',     // $priority: 'high', 'core', 'default', 'low'
        );
    }

    public function enqueue_widget_scripts()
    {
        wp_register_style( 
            'ticket-widget', 
            plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/index.css', 
            [], 
            false, 
        );
        wp_enqueue_style('ticket-widget');
        
        wp_register_script( 
            'ticket-widget',
            plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/index.js', 
            [], 
            false, 
            true 
        );
        wp_enqueue_script('ticket-widget');
    }


    public function setup_ticketing_rest_route()
    {
        register_rest_route( 
            'ict/ticketing', 
            '/send-request', 
            [
                'methods' => 'POST',
                'callback' => [$this, 'submit_support_ticket'],
                'permissions_callback' =>'__return_true'
            ]
        );
    }

    public function ticketing_widget_content()
    {
        ?>
            <div id="app"></div>
        <?php
    }

    //This is the old code I've tested to try using wp-ajax. 
    //At the moment I don't have created yet the callback for the rest endpoint
    /*public function submit_support_ticket( )
    {
        $request_type = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['reqType'] );
        $request_issuer = sanitize_email( $_POST['issuerEmail'] );
        $request_message = sanitize_textarea_field( $_POST['reqMessage'] );

        var_dump( $request_type, $request_issuer, $request_message );

        switch( $request_type ){
            case '1':
                $subject = 'Wordpress plugin problem';
                break;
            case '2':
                $subject = 'Wordpress theme problem';
                break;
            case '3':
                $subject = 'Wordpress plugin configuration support';
                break;
            case '4':
                $subject = 'Other issue';
                break;
        }
        //wp_mail( $to:string|array, $subject:string, $message:string, $headers:string|array, $attachments:string|array )

        $to = 'myemail@mywebsite.com';
        $headers[] = 'From: Ticketing WordPress <ticket.system@mywebsite.com>';
        $headers[] = '';
        $headers[] = '';
        $headers[] = '';

        if( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $request_message, $headers ) ){
            return [
                'status' => 'success',
                'message' => 'Email sent'
            ];
        } else {
            return [
                'status' => 'error',
                'message' => 'Email not sent'
            ];
        }
    }*/
}

$ticketing = new supportTicketSystem();

?>
```

At the mement my problem is how I can correctly load vue assets and bootstrap only for the widget. Is there any wp hook or action I can use to solve this problem?